# enforce a no spacebar when filling up input form

Tags: jquery

I have an input form for username, but I wish to not let the user to add space OR press spacebar when adding a username, how to do that in jquery, I mean, how to add such validation in my current code ?

```
 if(document.getElementById("cvusername")!== null && (cvusername == "" || cvusername.length < 5 || cvusername.length > 30)){
    alert("-username is required\n-should not be less than 5 characters\n and not greater than 30 characters");
    return false;
 }
```

Comment: where do you want to put this validation? in a button or in keypress?

Comment: once the submit button is pressed

Comment: If you are using jQuery you may want to make use of it instead of using the native DOM API directly in your example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check if there is a space character in the username:

```
if(document.getElementById("cvusername")!== null && 
  (cvusername == "" || 
   cvusername.length < 5 || 
   cvusername.length > 30 ||
   cvusername.indexOf(' ') != -1)){

    alert("-username is required\n-should not be less than 5 characters\n and not greater than 30 characters. It may also not contain spaces");
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

> I have an input form for username, but I wish to not let the user to add space OR press spacebar when adding a username, how to do that in jQuery?

On the *keyup* event, you could strip all whitespace characters from the `input` element.

```
$('input:text').keyup(function() {
    $(this).val(function(i, value) {
       return value.replace(/\s/, '');
    });
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/yehd6/).

> ...how to add such validation in my current code ?

To validate it again on submit, just use `$('input:text').val().search(/\s/) === -1`. That will return `true` if valid.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/Ass35/).

As the commenters suggested, you may want to also bind to the `paste` event and similar.

Make sure you confirm the whitespace is missing on the server side as well.

Comment: @sje397 - Add the same function to the onchange or blur event, will strip all whitespace from the value before it can be submitted.

Comment: what i need was, not allow the user to use the space bar for that single input form alone, that one i posted at the start of this query..so how to add such functionality/validation with the code i provided ?

Answer (score 2):

```
<input type="text" id="nospace" />

$('#nospace').keypress(function(event) {
    if (event.which == 32) {
        alert('No space');
        return false;
    }

     // this is for PASTE (ctrl + v)
  if(event.ctrlKey && event.which == 86) {
    alert('no space allowed');
    $(this).val($(this).val().replace(' ',''));
  }

});
```

Comment: Also, instead of detecting keyboard presses for paste, use the `paste` event.